# Gdx.input.setInputProcessor for several Screens. (LIBGDX, Conceptional)

Tags: libgdx, conceptual

I have:

- one Main ApplicationListener
- several screens which I set with `setScreen(screen)` in my Main depending on the context.
- each screen has their stages with their Inputlisteners.

Where and how do I set the `Gdx.input.setInputProcessor` for the different Screens ?

I mean when switching the screen I have to unset all listeners of the old screen and add the new ones from the new screen, so they do not overlap.
I cant do this in the constructor of the screen, because it is called only ones.
I could do it in the @Override.resize method of the screen, but I guess this is not the way I should do ?

Where should I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `Gdx.input.setInputProcessor()` in the `show()` method.

Because `screen.show()` will call everytime you call `setScreen(screen);`

And you don't need to remove the old one because the function `Gdx.input.setInputProcessor()` is simple like that:

```
@Override
public void setInputProcessor (InputProcessor processor) {
    this.processor = processor;
}
```

So it replaces the old one.